# How can I solve the unmet dependencies error?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools

I'm trying to running cerrbot-auto. But I am getting the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : Depends: python-minimal (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 python-virtualenv : Depends: python-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What I have already tried

```
$sudo apt-get install python-setuptools

$ apt-get -f install

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install python-virtualenv
```

but no commands at all have succeeded.

I'm a newbie
Thanks for any help that can be provided!

my info

```
Python 3.7.6

conda 4.9.2
(base) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-222:~$ apt-cache policy python

apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2.7.5-5ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

```
dpkg -l
ii  python-pip-whl                 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.1                 all          Python package installer
ii  python-pkg-resources           44.0.0-2                          all          Package Discovery and Resource Access>
ii  python2                        2.7.17-2ubuntu4                   amd64        interactive high-level object-oriente>
ii  python2-minimal                2.7.17-2ubuntu4                   amd64        minimal subset of the Python2 language
ii  python2.7                      2.7.18-1~20.04                    amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriente>
ii  python2.7-minimal              2.7.18-1~20.04                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language>
ii  python3                        3.8.2-0ubuntu2                    amd64        interactive high-level object-oriente>
...
ii  python3-venv                   3.8.2-0ubuntu2                    amd64        pyvenv-3 binary for python3 (default >
ii  python3-virtualenv             20.0.17-1                         all          Python virtual environment creator
...
ii  python3.8                      3.8.5-1~20.04                     amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriente>
ii  python3.8-minimal              3.8.5-1~20.04                     amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language>
ii  python3.8-venv                 3.8.5-1~20.04                     amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriente>
```

Comment: tell me you using pip3 or pip?

Comment: I usually use pip

Comment: But I'm really bad at this, maybe.. first few times I used conda install instead of pip